# the Bokeh plot not show up on chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, bokeh

I had code on jupyter notebook:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, show

x = [1,2,3,4,5]

y = [6,7,8,9,10]

output_file("Line.htlm")

f = figure()
f.line(x,y)
show(f)
```

No Error occured but i recieved this on chorme:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACT19.png)

But when try the html result file with firefox, it was worked:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqAaZ.png)

Could someone teach me how to fix the problem one chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the Bokeh HTML output. But you have mis-named your output file **.ht*lm*** instead of **.html** so chrome has just opened the output as plain text. Also, if you you would like to see output inline in the notebook itself, instead of a new tab, use `output_notebook`.